# Verified email in Spring Boot/Security registration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

How to verify an email provided during registration is a real one? Confirmation link is an obvious choice, but I've seen websites where some kind of email verification happens right after you click 'register'. If email is fake, the process stops. How can this be done in Spring? 
(example: safaribooksonline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check if the mail got bounced. If it does, it's not a valid email. You can use an api provided by [neverbounce](https://neverbounce.com/) and [here is the github link](https://github.com/NeverBounce/NeverBounceApi-Java) for that in java.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the MailboxValidator API.

Just sign up for the free API key at https://www.mailboxvalidator.com/plans#api

Then you can use the Java code at https://github.com/MailboxValidator/mailboxvalidator-java or use Maven https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mailboxvalidator/mailboxvalidator-java/1.0.0